# Creating a general function

Tags: python, numpy

I have a function defintion -

[image]

Now I have to create a function like this-

[image]

The problem is that since there are 4 combinations of (t,c)(where t is the feature and c is the class) which can occur that is (t,c) , (t',c) , (t,c') , (t', c'). So according to the values of t,c the function defintion will also change.
Is there any method apart from calculating a , b ,c ,d 4 times and then summing the function values?

The dataset looks like this-

```
feature file_frequency_M file_frequency_B
     abc          2                5
```

my attempt-

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('.csv')
score = []

###list =[(t,c) ,(t,c0),(t0,c),(t0,c0)]  ##representation of the combination of (t,c)
l=152+1394

for index, row in dataset.iterrows():
    a = row['file_frequency_M']
    b = row['file_frequency_B']
    c = 152 - a        
    d = 1394 - b
    temp_score = 0
    tmp1 = 0
    tmp2 = 0
    tmp3 = 0
    tmp4 = 0
    for i in range(4):
        if i == 0:
            if a == 0:
                tmp1 = 0
            else:
                tmp1 = log10(((a * l) / (a + c) * (a + b)))
        temp_score += tmp1
        if i == 1:
            if b == 0:
                tmp2 = 0
            else:
                tmp2 = log10(((b * l) / (b + d) * (b + a)))
        temp_score += tmp2    
        if i == 2:
            if c == 0:
                tmp3 = 0
            else:
                tmp3 = log10(((c * l) / (c + a) * (c + d)))
        temp_score += tmp3
        if i == 3:
            if d == 0:
                tmp4 = 0
            else:
                tmp4 = log10(((d * l) / (d + b) * (d + c)))
        temp_score += tmp4
    score.append(temp_score)
np.savetxt("m.csv", score, delimiter=",")
```

Comment: What is your current solution? If you show me your current solution I might be able to improve it, but I won't try to solve your problem from scratch without even having a proper description.

Comment: @Scotty1-Its a very basic solution..but I will post it anyways

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save a lot of code repetition by creating a function representation of `I(t,c)`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from math import log10

dataset = pd.read_csv('.csv')
score = []

###list =[(t,c) ,(t,c0),(t0,c),(t0,c0)]  ##representation of the combination of (t,c)
l=152+1394

def I(a,b,c,n):
    """Returns I(t,c) = A*N/((A+C)*(A+B))"""
    if a == 0: 
        return 0
    return log10((a * n) / ((a + c) * (a + b)))

for index, row in dataset.iterrows():
    a = row['file_frequency_M']
    b = row['file_frequency_B']
    c = 152 - a        
    d = 1394 - b

    tmp1 = I(a,b,c,l)
    tmp2 = I(b,a,d,l)
    tmp3 = I(c,d,a,l)
    tmp4 = I(d,c,b,l)
    temp_score = sum(tmp1,tmp2,tmp3,tmp4)
    score.append(temp_score)

np.savetxt("m.csv", score, delimiter=",")
```

**Note:** you appear to have an error in your code, according to the image of your function definition, it should be:

```
log10((a * n) / ((a + c) * (a + b)))
```

not

```
log10(((a * l) / (a + c) * (a + b)))
```

(note the parentheses placement).